# PHP 4 - Undefined class name 

Tags: php, oop, class, php4

In PHP 4, if you use a class before it's defined you get this error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class name
>   'foo' in...

My code is:

```
function do_stuff(){
  if(foo::what()) ... // this code is before the php file with the foo class is included    
}

class foo{
  function what(){
  ...
  }
}

do_stuff();
```

is there any workaround for this (besides telling the people who use your script to update to php5) ?

Comment: No, upgrade to PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Anyway, why use PHP 4, I mean WTF that is old as shit

Comment: Petah: sometimes you're just stuck with outdated technology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use:

```
call_user_func(array('foo', 'what'));
```

which would cause the class/method to be checked at runtime rather than compile time.

Comment: that's looks ugly.. I just noticed this happens with functions too. PHP 4 is so retarded :(

Answer (score 1):

Define your classes in a file which is `require_once()`d at the start of your script.

Answer (score 1):

if php4, you can test the existence of a class with [`class_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php). So to be compatible with php5, you can write this type of code :

```
<?php
function __autoload($classname) {
    include("classes/$classname.class.php");   
}

if (!class_exists('foo')) __autoload('foo');
```